# Azure Web App is Timing Out

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.0

After a deploy to our Azure Web App, we are getting 500 timeouts on any request to the service:

> 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

I have enabled logging in web.config and the logs are showing no exceptions or anything wierd on startup. Only this in stdout_abdce_2016wxyz.log:

`Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

[image: stdouts]

Thing is I have loads of logs with the same contents. every 3minutes (approx) There seems to be a new one generated.

Running AspNet Core RTM (after doing an upgrade from RC1. web.config I took from the aspnet/IIS repository on github. The project runs and functions fine locally on my development PC

Comment: Did you configure your app to listen on port 5000?

Comment: Yeah my program.cs (entry point)

```.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
```

I have some RC2 projects with a similar WebHostBuilder that work fine in Azure. Is it that UseUrls() extension?

Comment: I believe that's your issue. Answer coming.

Comment: Are you registering the IIS/:ASP.NET Core Module middleware? `.UseIISIntegration()` in Program.cs and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",``  in your project.json's dependencies/tools sections? Check the MusicStore Samples on github https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/1.0.0/src/MusicStore.Standalone/Program.cs#L19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to hook into port 5000, I'm pretty sure this is your issue. Azure Web Apps only support ports 80 and 443.

I believe you'll be able to read the port value to use, from the environment.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, because the ASP.NET Core Module will be responsible for starting the application and using the IIS as reverse proxy to it. I'm running an app on 8080. The question is more if the OP registered the IIS Middleware?

Comment: I did not and adding IIS to my host builder was all that was needed